# How to post the json data on web API

Tags: json

How can I post using JSON on Web API?

Post Data:

```
user_name (required)
user_email  (required, valid email)
user_phone (required, Numeric, 10 Digit)
user_password (required, Minimum 8 Characters)
```

Response data:

```
{"status":"success","msg":"Register"}
```

Comment: can you clear? are you posting data to your web  and receiving the output json?

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to hit a web service by passing some values to web, you can use following logic.

**Your html/php page from where you are sending request for web api**

```
var dataString='user_email=abc@domain.com&user_phone=xxxxxxxxx&user_password=*******';
$.post( "your_url.php",dataString, function( data ) 
{
    alert(data);// this will return json data
    now parse json using JSON.parse(data)
});
```

**Note:
server api page if using php
your_url.php**

```
 $_POST['user_email'];
$_POST['user_password'];
$_POST['user_phone'];
if(your condition match)
{
    $respnse['status']='success';
    $respnse['message']='register';
    echo json_encode($respnse);
}
```